# UnmappableCharacterException when running packaged program

Tags: java, nio

I am loading some text from a database and write it to a file. If I run my program from inside Eclipse everything works, but if I package the program with Maven I get an `UnmappableCharacterException`.

I create a `BufferedWriter` as following:

```
final BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(csvFile, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

The exception is thrown when I call `writer.flush`.

This is the stacktrace:

```
java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1
        at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
        at com.siemens.okhbimporter.importers.NodeWriter.run(NodeWriter.java:85)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I only pass Strings to the `write()` method. If I set the charset to UTF-8 everything works. What is going on here?

The error occurs at the String `Knoten;1;1;false;Fügetechnik;;2003-06-11 00:00:00;2003-06-11 00:00:00;`. I can not see characters that are not in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Javadocs for [CharsetEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html), [CharsetDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) and [UnmappableCharacterException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/UnmappableCharacterException.html) are pretty clear on what happens when a character can not be represented in the chosen charset encoding, which is what happens in your case. Your input strings contains characters that can not be represented in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: This does not explain why the program runs once and once not. I added the input string and I do not see characters that can not be represented by ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Seems like you will have to add some additional debugging code to catch the exact input that causes it. The string you provided can not cause UCE by it self, but still it is obvious that `BufferedWriter` contains a character which is outside of ISO-8859-1 range.

Answer (score 1):

Files.newBufferedWriter returns a Writer that throws UnmappableCharacterException (reports encoding errors) but you can create a BufferedWriter that writes to a Path and replaces erroneous input by using Files.newOutputStream instead. For example the code below

```
try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(Files.newOutputStream(path), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII))) {
    writer.write("español");
}
```

outputs "espa?ol".